# convert every element in bash array to x number of significant digits

Tags: arrays, bash, significant-digits

I know you can alter the amount of floating points in a textfile of values with something along the lines of:

```
awk '{printf("%.2g",$1)}' filename.txt
```

which will reduce everything to two decimal digits. However, if I have a string in bash:

```
echo ${array1}
-82.534592 -82.511200 -82.478912 -82.490959 -82.521393 -82.529610 -82.503510 -82.478218
```

How do I convert all values in the array to have x number of significant digits / floating point values? For example, if I wanted everything to have 2 significant digits, the output would be:

```
echo ${new_array1}
-82.53 -82.51 -82.48 -82.49 -82.52 -82.53 -82.50 -82.48
```

Comment: It looks like you don't have an array, but a blank separated string.

Comment: For future reference, the values you want have 4 significant figures. The value you’re referring to is just the number of digits after the decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

Your `array1` doesn't seem to be an array because to see all elements in the array, you'd have to use `echo "${array1[@]}"`. `${array1}` prints just the first element of an array, if it is one.

You can create an array like this:

```sh
array1=(-82.534592 -82.511200 -82.478912 -82.490959 -82.521393 -82.529610 -82.503510 -82.478218)
```

To print all elements rounded to two digits after the decimal point:

```
$ printf '%.2f\n' "${array1[@]}"
-82.53
-82.51
-82.48
-82.49
-82.52
-82.53
-82.50
-82.48
```

To read that output into a new array:

```sh
readarray -t newarray1 < <(printf '%.2f\n' "${array1[@]}")
```

And to inspect the new array:

```
$ declare -p newarray1
declare -a newarray1=([0]="-82.53" [1]="-82.51" [2]="-82.48" [3]="-82.49" [4]="-82.52" [5]="-82.53" [6]="-82.50" [7]="-82.48")
```